# Rebuilding RPM results in "invalid numeric value"

Tags: linux, bash, centos, rpm

I am attempting to add some config changes to Bash and repackage it as an RPM in CentOS x86.  This is not something I've done before, so I'm at the mercy of info I've found around the internet.

I am at the point where I have created my .spec file, and am attempting to run the following command:

```
rpmbuild -ba bash.spec
```

I get the following error as a result:

```
error: invalid numeric value: -pl: %patch119 -pl -b .history_syslog
```

The line referenced is verbatim in the error above (after the "-pl:").  If the "-pl" is what it thinks is the issue, I'm confused, because every other patch entry in the list (that existed before I edited it) is formatted exactly the same, e.g. -

```
%patch108 -pl -b .readline_oom
```

I'm not seeing a lot of answers when searching.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's in `.history_syslog`?

Comment: I think the issue has more to do with the contents of .history_syslog. Sounds like the patch is malformed.

Comment: Are you sure the other patches have "**-pl**" and not "**-p1**"? The latter would make much more sense, since it is argument for `patch`...

Comment: @terdon Nothing is in .history_syslog. That's the argument to `-b`, and will be used as the extension for backed-up versions of patched files. It's not relevant to the error.

Comment: @mattdm thanks, I though it was being read by the command.

Comment: @terdon It's a little weird. (Because, _historical_.) The actual patch to apply is given earlier in the file (in the section where you list package source files, basically), and then the number in the patch macro (here, 119) is used to find the right one.

Answer (score 3):

What we have here is a *font* issue. Your `l` (lower case L) and `1` (numeral one) look too similar. The error message is completely correct and pretty close to actually informative, as far as RPM error messages go: it says

```
error: invalid numeric value: -pl: %patch119 -pl -b .history_syslog
```

This breaks down into separate fields separated by :.

- **error** yep.
- **invalid numeric value** the specific problem
- **-pl** the part of the line that has the problem
- **%patch119 -pl -b .history_syslog** the whole line with the error

So, it's saying that there's an invalid numeric value in `-pl`. And sure enough, l is not a numeric value.

You have given `l` for your working patch 108 as well in your question, but I suspect that it's actually a `1` in the file. It is argument for the `-p` option of `patch`, which tells it how many prefix directories it should strip from file name when looking for a file to patch (see the `patch(1)` man page for details).

Comment: +1 (serves me right for writing comments instead of answers). :)

Comment: @peterph Yeah, your comment came in while I was writing. :) Hopefully people find it helpful to have the error message broken down like this.

Comment: I think I just gave myself a concussion from the force of the self-administered smack to the forehead.  This would explain why I couldn't find much on the error.

Thanks everyone.  Very much obliged.